# Button class switch in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I want to switch class button when user click on it.
This is the button code I have right now

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-bordered" id="toggle-job">Grab this work</button>
```

Below the code to handle the button click

```
$('#toggle-job').click(function(e){
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "btn-success" ) ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "btn-success" ).addClass( "btn-custom" );
        $( this ).text("Drop this work");
    };
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "btn-custom" ) ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "btn-custom" ).addClass( "btn-success" );
        $( this ).text("Grab this work");
    };
    $( "#action-box" ).toggle();
    $( "#photoCrop" ).toggle();
});
```

The toggle code works properly...so the related divs show or hide
I'm pretty sure I'm doing some silly error...but I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/remove class to a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285555/add-remove-class-to-a-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your second `if statement` to an `else if statement`, that should work.

Right now your first if case changes the class to `btn-custom`, but right after that the second `if` changes it back to `btn-success`.

Comment: I'm really stupid! Thanks a lot twain. By the way...there could be a more elegant way to switch class?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. For a more easy / elegant way have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery